# VS Code doesn't complete $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I am trying out VS Code for an AngularJs app. Very first file and already something is not working, which I thought was supposed to.

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyModule", ['ngRoute']);
```

Ok, so far so good. It asked me to figure out what 'angular' is and I happily clicked the option that placed a `<reference/>` line at the top of the file.

Ok, how about config now...

```
myModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
});
```

Ok, shouldn't I get a suggestion of ".when" at this point? I don't. I get "No suggestions." instead.

What am I doing wrong?

I even manually included another `<reference/>` tag at the top, pointing it to angular-route.d.ts file. Doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in your case `angular` is a globally available variable (which will be added to the `window` object when the script is loaded) and the `$routeProvider` is just a regular parameter name.

For all global objects that are somehow "imported" (or declared as available), VS Code figures out where this probably comes from by using the TypeScript definition files. There is no way that VS Code can figure out that some parameter name comes from the angular router. That's just an angular specific behavior that a function passed to the `config` method will get some angular dependency injected. You could of course write some other methods that use this parameter name.

```
function calcSquare($routeProvider) {
  return $routeProvider * $routeProvider;
}
```

Just by having a parameter named like that, it would not be correct to guess the type.

When using TypeScript, you can declare these types of parameters so that you receive support from your IDE:

```
myModule.config(function($routeProvider: angular.route.IRouteProvider) {
  // $routeProvider. // auto-completion available here
});
```